# Password game using absorption and distribution laws

Tags: java, passwords

So, here is my code.  What I am trying to do is when I input the correct value for the password the first time it prints Valid only once.  But, if I type in the correct password the first time it continually writes 'valid' forever.  Also, if I don't type in the correct number the first time then when I do type in the correct password it just stops the code.  How would I fix both of these problems?

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int password= 9320;
    int user = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter a password: :");
    user = sc.nextInt();

    while(user==password){
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }

    while(user!=password){
        System.out.println("INVALID");
        System.out.println("Enter the password again");
        user = sc.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: I am mainly concerned with the program saying 'Valid' over and over again

Comment: `while(user==password){` there's no change in either variable within the loop so it will obviously loop forever if they are equal.

Comment: By attaching a debugger. "Why isn't this code working" is off-topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I feel like a noob but, how would I make the loop stop?

Comment: Learn the language, then don't use a loop but a condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int password= 9320;
int user = 0;

System.out.print("Enter a password: :");
user = sc.nextInt();

while(user!=password){
    System.out.println("INVALID");
    System.out.println("Enter the password again");
    user = sc.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Valid");
```